# Rails 3 - Association validation in the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have a Rails 3 program with a User model, a CreditCard model, and then a Payment model.  The User has_many CreditCards, and the CreditCard has_many Payments.

In my application, when a User makes a new Payment, he selects from a list of his cards which CreditCard he would like to use to Pay.  I would like to add an extra validation in the code though to make sure that the credit_card_id submitted to the Payment.create() function is actually one owned by the current user.

It feels like that validation would have to take place in the controller, right?  Or is there a best practice for dealing with this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will definitely want to do this validation in your model.  It is usually considered a Rails best practice to keep your [controllers skinny](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model) and have fat models.

Assuming that a Payment belongs to a user and that a Payment belongs to a credit card(Im assuming this since you have a credit_card_id field on your payment) you can do something like this.

```
Class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :credit_card

  validate :credit_card_belongs_to_user

  def credit_card_belongs_to_user
    errors.add(:credit_card, 'does not belong to you') unless user == credit_card.user
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

add a validation for payment.  payment is most probably associated to a user via `belongs_to` so I suggest add the following validation

```
# payment.rb
belongs_to :user
validate :validates_credit_card_belongs_to_user

private

def validates_credit_card_belongs_to_user
  unless user.credit_card.where(id: credit_card_id).exists?
    errors.add(:credit_card_id, 'is not owned by this user')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also fetch credit card like this [ in the before filter ] in the PaymentsController

@credit_card = current_user.credit_cards.find(params[:credit_card_id])

and then

@payment = @credit_card.payments.build(params[:payment])

That way you will be sure that it is credit_card owned by current_user.